# Java: Return same type values as one JSON object

Tags: java, json

Suppose I have 3 different dates as following:

```
try {

    DateDetails GetDateDetailsResp = GET.getDateDetails;

    Date date1 = GetDateDetailsResp.dateDetails.date1;
    Date date2 = GetDateDetailsResp.dateDetails.date2;
    Date date3 = GetDateDetailsResp.dateDetails.date3;
}
```

I need to return them all as one `JSON` object using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(JSONobject);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(jsonString);
```

So how I can map the 3 dates with JSONobject to be returned as one JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best sulution than my first answer.

```
@Data
    public static class ResponseVo {
        private Object1 obj1;

        private Object2 obj2;

        public  static ResponseVo getInstance(Object1 obj1, Object2 obj2) {
            ResponseVo vo = new ResponseVo();
            vo.setObj1(obj1);
            vo.setObj2(obj2);
            return vo;
        }
    }

    @Data
    public static class Object1{
        private String object1String;

        private Integer object1Integer;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Object2 {
        private String object2String;

        private Integer object2Integer;

        private Object1 object2Obj;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseVo> test() {

        Object1 object1 = new Object1();
        object1.setObject1Integer(1);
        object1.setObject1String("obj1");

        Object2 object2 = new Object2();
        object2.setObject2String("obj2");
        object2.setObject2Integer(2);
        object2.setObject2Obj(object1);



        return new ResponseEntity<>(ResponseVo.getInstance(object1, object2), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And here is the json data.

```
{
  "obj1": {
    "object1String": "obj1",
    "object1Integer": 1
  },
  "obj2": {
    "object2String": "obj2",
    "object2Integer": 2,
    "object2Obj": {
      "object1String": "obj1",
      "object1Integer": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the another solution.

```
@Data
    public static class Object1{
        private String object1String;

        private Integer object1Integer;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Object2 {
        private String object2String;

        private Integer object2Integer;

        private Object1 object2Obj;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<Map> test() {

        Object1 object1 = new Object1();
        object1.setObject1Integer(1);
        object1.setObject1String("obj1");

        Object2 object2 = new Object2();
        object2.setObject2String("obj2");
        object2.setObject2Integer(2);
        object2.setObject2Obj(object1);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map map = mapper.convertValue(object1, Map.class);
        map.putAll(mapper.convertValue(object2, Map.class));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Here is the json data.

```
{
  "object1String": "obj1",
  "object1Integer": 1,
  "object2String": "obj2",
  "object2Integer": 2,
  "object2Obj": {
    "object1String": "obj1",
    "object1Integer": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Calling the annotation `@Data` required at each class or depending on used IDE?

Comment: @Eng7 My english  is`t  good  Can you please explain your word by easy word?. Forgive me.